# Import COM interfaces from an olb file into VC6

Tags: c++, com, mfc, visual-c++-6

*Please don't tell me not to use VC6, it's a legacy project.*

I have an olb file that contains COM interfaces, and I need to create a header and cpp file containing wrapper classes derived from COleDispatchDriver. I've done it before, but now I can't remember the steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the ClassWizard (from the View menu or Ctrl+W - I think). The Add Class button has a 'From a Type Library' option.